# Comment thread in Django

Tags: python, django

I am building up a simple Django app with blogs and comments on blogs. While developing the comment thread, I am getting the error "no such table: blog_commentsonpost" when I try to enter a comment. Can someone help me to solve the issue.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def get_type(self):
    return "post"

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class CommentsOnPost(models.Model):

author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment')
post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

@classmethod
def create(cls, author, text, post):
    postcomment = cls(author=author,
                  post_id=post,
                  text=text, created_date=timezone.now,
                  published_date=timezone.now)

    return postcomment
```

views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post
redirect_field_name = 'post_detail'

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    author = request.user
    text  = request.POST['postcomment']
    post  = request.POST['post']

    postcomment = CommentsOnPost()
    postcomment.text = text
    postcomment.author = author
    postcomment.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/post/{}'.format(post))
```

html

```
  <form method="POST" class="post-form" >{% csrf_token %}
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="postcomment">Comments:</label>
                                  <textarea class="form-control" name="postcomment" rows="5"></textarea>
                              </div>
                              <input type="hidden" name="post" value="{{ post.id }}">
                              <div>
                                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="color:blue;" value="Comment"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

If it is a new app, did you add it to the settings.py?